# Installing gphoto2 on mac os x Yosemite - issue with ./configure

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, libgphoto2

I am trying to install gphoto2 on my macbook pro. I installed the tar.gz from their website and from terminal I `cd Downloads` and run `./configure` as the README file recommends doing. I keep receiving this error:

```
checking for pkg-config... false
configure: error: 
*** Build requires pkg-config
***
*** Possible solutions:
***   - set PKG_CONFIG to where your pkg-config is located
***   - set PATH to include the directory where pkg-config is installed
***   - get it from http://freedesktop.org/software/pkgconfig/ and install it
```

I have Xcode 6 installed, as well as Command Line tools (tested it by running gcc in terminal). What am I doing wrong? What should I do?

Also, should I install gphoto2 or libgphoto2?

Comment: what does `which pkg-config` say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't bother faffing around with building it yourself. I would install `homebrew` from [here](http://brew.sh).

Then you can simply do

```
brew install gphoto2
```

and you will also have a decent package manager if you want to install other cool stuff later on - e.g. ImageMagick, gawk, GNU sed, swatch, youtube-downloader, wxWidgets, vips, redis, sox, ffmpeg. To find other cool stuff that can be managed with `homebrew` just do

```
brew search
```